# How to access S3 using IAM role from my local machine

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a AWS account (id : `111111`) and I have a ARN role created (aws id : `arn:aws:iam::222222:role/developenv`).

From the AWS CLI I am able to access the resource created in id : `222222` by using `--profile`. But I am not sure how to achieve it in Java for accessing S3.

I know one way of doing is using a temporary credentials:

```
 AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
                                                    .withRoleArn(roleARN)
                                                    .withRoleSessionName(roleSessionName);
            stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
            GetSessionTokenRequest getSessionTokenRequest = new GetSessionTokenRequest();
            getSessionTokenRequest.setDurationSeconds(7200);
```

My question is: Is there a way to achieve this without requesting for Temporary credentials and access the bucket created in account `222222`?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you asking how to access services by using the IAM Role, via the AWS Java SDK? When you use `--profile` with the AWS CLI, is the definition for that profile an IAM Role?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein- yes, I have configured the profile in my aws cli. [profile dev]
    role_arn = arn:aws:iam::222222:role/developenv
    source_profile = default
 region = us-east-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the correct method.

An IAM Role does not, itself, have credentials. Instead, an IAM User can *assume* an IAM Role, which will provide temporary credentials that have the permissions associated with the role.

When specifying a role in a AWS CLI profile, the CLI actually calls `AssumeRole` on your behalf. These credentials can remain valid for a maximum of **12 hours**.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for S3, it is possible to bypass temporary credentials mechanism and permanently allow another role in another account to access to a bucket. Please follow https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/ to enable this.